A Chinese manhua/manga/manhwa about a girl who was cheated on by her fiance with her sister, died, and reincarnated to another world having same fate
So there's this girl (female MC,brown hair), who was cheated on by her fiance with her sister (purple hair). Her sister and fiance killed her, and she was transported in the past, something like ancient China? (Help! IDK what I'm talking about!) She was aware of what was happening though,and is trying to go to the real world.
And then she had the same fate in there. Her fiance cheated on her with her sister, but she was engaged to an even better guy (male MC) who was pretending to be sick but is actually pretty strong and handsome and rich. That guy has blue hair, and is the brother of the female MC's ex-fiance.
Also, the female MC had a brother in her new life who was a general, and he was kind. And she also had two female friends who were twin sisters—but also her bodyguards.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?
